# Changes in REST API response to get the test run results from the VSTS tool

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have observed some changes in JSON response for the below REST API to get the test run results from VSTS tool.

GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0-preview.5

Below is the link where I got the above API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/results/list?view=vsts-rest-5.0

Before update it use to give us the Test Plan Id and Test Suite Id for a test run Id. Now these two values are not provided by the current API response.

I am sure that there have been made some changes in the response in same version of API. 
Is there any published a list of such changes ?

Answer (score 0):

In the REST API to [Get Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/results/get?view=vsts-rest-5.0), it can not response with Test Plan Id and Test Suite Id. It only response with the test result(s) with the Run id.

If you want to get Test Plan Id from a given Test Run Id, you should use the REST API [Get Test Run By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/runs/get%20test%20run%20by%20id?view=vsts-rest-5.0) instead, then you can get the plan id it belongs to.

Comment: I need the test run outcome which I can get through run ID. But how do I map that outcome to the particular test case and a particular suite in which that test case is existing in test plan hub.
Two days before I was getting Test Plan Id and Test suite Id in the response of the API which I mentioned in my question. I have old response and new response in notepad and there is a difference in response.

Comment: AFAIK, Get Test results REST API does not response with test plan and test suite. And what di you mean "how do I map that outcome to the particular test case and a particular suite in which that test case is existing in test plan hub"?

Comment: I want to know the outcomes of all test cases which are present in a particular suite under test plan of VSTS.
Since, I am unable to get test case outcome based on test case Id. I am trying to get it through test run ID and I am getting It. but not getting the suite Id for that test run ID. so, How will I know that the  test run is for which test case (because a same test case can present in multiple suites).

Comment: @HansmukhJain You can not get all the thinfs from one REST API, try will use multiple REST APIs to achieve.